# Undefined offset in post with array

Tags: php, arrays, post

I've been struggling with this stuff for two days, I need help, lol.
I'm trying to handle a post that has some inputs as an array.

To understand the structure of the array, here's a print_r($_POST)

print_r($_POST):

```
Array
(
[prov] => 49
[almacen] => 1
[fecha] => 24-01-2014
[a] => Array
    (
        ['1545'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        ['908'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

    )

[p] => Array
    (
        ['1545'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0.6
            )

        ['908'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

[d] => Array
    (
        ['1545'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 20
            )

        ['908'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

[e] => Array
    (
        ['1545'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2
            )

        ['908'] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

)
```

If I do a print_r($_POST["p"]) this is what I get (as expected):

```
Array
(
['1545'] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0.6
    )

['908'] => Array
    (
        [0] => 0
    )

)
```

but, if I try to go further with print_r($_POST["p"][0]), I receive a:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

or print_r($_POST["p"]["1545"]) also fails with undefined offset.

How can I get $_POST["p"]["1545"] not returning undefined.

Thanks!

Comment: `$_POST['p'][1545]` should work without problems?

Comment: well `$_POST["p"][0]` actually doesn't exist, but there is no reason `print_r($_POST["p"]["1545"])` returns `undefined offset`

Comment: $_POST['p'][1545] and $_POST['p']["1545"] both give
Undefined offset: 1545

Comment: @monxas check http://stackoverflow.com/a/21380543/829533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to get `1545` with `'`

```
print_r($_POST["p"]["'1545'"]);
```

it seems like `'1545'` is the actual key for array `$_POST['p']`

> it means that you have error in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print_r($_POST["p"]["1545"][0])
```

Comment: answer:
Undefined index: 1545

Comment: if 1545 does not exist, no more nested keys would exist